# PHP Redirect from require_once

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a different page when a value is entered into 'username' on my login form. But a warning appear saying "cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Zach/Sites/Project2/proj2Functions.php:10) in /Users/Zach/Sites/Project2/redirect.php on line 3"

I put the code all the way at the top so I thought the redirect would work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for the login:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim ($_POST["password"]);

    if (has_presence($username)) {
        redirect_to("Homepage2.php");
    }
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Start Collay Login(beginLogin)</title>
 </head>
 <body>

     <?php echo "This is the first login page"; ?>


     <form action="beginLogin.php" method="post">
     Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br>
     Password: <input type="text" name="password" value=""><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the redirect file:

```
<?php 
function redirect_to($new_location) {
        header("Location: " . $new_location);
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect file code should be the first thing to appear on the page so even if there is a blank space or a line break before the `<?php` then it will not work or you may turn output_buffering on in your php.ini file by assigning it a value (4096) is generally a good value..

Hope this helps,

Take care and Happy coding..